# Not connecting to internet on iOS 9 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9, xcode7

I'm using Xcode 7. when iOS 9 simulator did not connect to internet, I added App transport security to info.plist to allow insecure communication. It did work for some time. But again, it has stopped working. Have tried 'reset content and settings', restarting. nothing seems to work. 
Has anyone come across this? know how to solve?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find detail related to issue here
[App Transport Security Exceptions in iOS 9 and OSX 10.11](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/)

Apple provides a way to disable ATS altogether

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

There are other keys that you can use to configure App Transport Security as well

```
NSRequiresCertificateTransparency
NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
NSTemporaryThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads
NSTemporaryThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion
NSTemporaryThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy
```